# What's the cause of this strange crash behavior related to Python, Anaconda, Matplotlib, MKL, & Jupyter?

Tags: ubuntu, python, crash, matplotlib, jupyter

We're pretty stumped on this crash issue as we don't get any tracebacks or other messages about what's actually wrong so it's been tough to debug.  Anyhow, here goes.

We have a workstation for running our analysis work in Python.  The gist of the problem is that when we work on notebooks (or run the test script shown below), the system crashes.  The crash consists of a freeze of the OS and then a restart.  There is nothing that tells us what happened, just that the machine freezes and restarts.

The crashes occurs most often when we run a notebook and ask the notebook to do a bit too much plotting.  It's impossible for us to define "too much plotting" exactly but the example below is an extreme case to force the issue.  The script sometimes causes a crash quickly and sometimes takes a bit of time.  But inevitably, it will cause a crash.

Here's some of the stuff what we're running that seems, based on our research so far, to be part of the problem:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Anaconda 5.2.0 with MKL
- Numpy 1.16.2
- Matplotlib 3.0.3
- Jupyter 1.0.0

The summary of the findings is:

1. The base Anaconda installation uses Numpy with MKL and has Matplotlib linked to its dependencies within the Anaconda distribution.  Running the test script below with Python causes a crash every single time.  ETA: We tried different backends for Matplotlib but it didn't make a difference.
2. If we run the test script from an Anaconda distribution where Numpy was installed by Conda but *not* with MKL and Matplotlib was installed via pip and *not* via Conda, then the script runs fine.  If we use either MKL *or* Conda instead of pip to install Matplotlib, we get the crash.  We can also run the script fine with a non-Anaconda distribution with everything installed via pip (and no other MKL linking).
3. If we create a Jupyter notebook version of the script (one plot per cell) and run all cells, the notebook will cause the crash.  So all of our gains in point 2 are wiped out just by using Jupyter.
4. We typically run Jupyter in a Docker container and behind a Nginx reverse proxy.  We ruled this out as a cause because the Docker images are also Ubuntu 18.04 and we ran the tests directly on the host machine to rule out any Docker issues.
5. When we track the resource usage, we find naturally that with MKL, CPU usage gets into the 300-400% range.  We have a 12 core CPU and have routinely hit higher % values.  We barely use a gig of memory when running the test script while having 128GB capacity and routinely run data analyses that push us far higher than that 1 gb.

That about covers what we've been able to figure out.  Since the crashes were tied so much to plotting, it seemed pretty obvious that tweaks to Matplotlib created at least a partial fix.  The MKL issue added a puzzling confounder on top of that but we thought we had a workaround.  But then when we went to back to test it in Jupyter, it turns out that even though we got the script running, point 4 still shows we haven't totally fixed everything.

And that brings us to to this post.  Nothing I've seen online comes remotely close to matching what we're observing and I've never seen anything like it.  I am completely out of ideas and have no resorted to wondering if it's actually a hardware issue.

Any help cracking this nut would be greatly appreciated.  I'm thinking of trying this out on our workstation with a Linux distro other than Ubuntu.

```
# Test Script
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# None of the dataframe stuff seems to matter nor the figure size, just 
# that we're trying to plot a bunch
n = 100000
figsize = (8, 6)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': np.cumsum(np.random.rand(n)) / np.arange(1, n+1, 1),
        'B': np.cumsum(np.random.rand(n)) / np.arange(1, n+1, 1),
        'C': np.cumsum(np.random.rand(n)) / np.arange(1, n+1, 1)
    },
    index=pd.date_range('2001-01-01 12:00:00', freq='S', periods=n)
)
df.plot(figsize=figsize)
# closing the figures just in case, but doesn't make a difference
plt.close(plt.gcf())

...
# Repeat the dataframe and plotting snippet a lot, like ~100x
...
```

ADDED:
My colleague found this post this morning.  Making a stronger case for hardware issue. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/python-matplotlib-script-crashes-system/44052/10

REVISED UPDATE:
Turning off hyperthreading in the BIOS did not work.  But following the boot suggestions from that post on manjaro.org *did* help, as long as they were not done in conjunction with turning off hyperthreading in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *workaround* is to use the boot setting `apci=off` as mentioned in this forum post:  https://forum.manjaro.org/t/python-matplotlib-script-crashes-system/44052/10

This is acceptable to us but if someone has an actual fix or explanation or really anything to add to this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issues with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS system and the latest Anaconda fresh installation. Interestingly, I had exactly the same behaviour (freeze + system crash) on Windows 10 Pro (completely up-to-date).

AFAIK, Windows doesn't allow booting without ACPI. However, Ubuntu does, and changing the grub boot settings by adding `acpi=off` solved the issue.

However, this didn't solve the issue for the Windows partition, since ACPI is something Windows expects. My Argentinean colleague (who's really awesome) suggested trying an earlier version of matplotlib. So, I used the command `conda install matplotlib=2.2.3` to downgrade to version 2.2.3.

<strike>Downgrading immediately solved the issue on Ubuntu and Windows! So, I suggest downgrading for now until the matplotlib developers solve this issue. It also means you don't have to disable ACPI or any other options which are (in this novice's estimation) probably doing nice things in the background and are therefore better to keep on.</strike>

Actually, this worked for the first example in the gallery of matplotlib. But after trying further examples via scripts and in jupyter notebook, it still crashes with 2.2.3. So, I upgraded back to the latest matplotlib and added back `acpi=off`, but this still resulted in freeze + crash while plotting a histogram in jupyter notebook. So, I added `intel_pstate=disable` and keeping at the latest version of matplotlib this was able to run through a jupyter notebook.

UPDATE: One drawback of this is that the system doesn't power-down properly :/ Ubuntu will hang towards the very end of its power-down with these settings and I have to manually power off the machine. Not sure if it's technically great for the hardware.